# How to print lines based on values in multiple columns

Tags: awk, printing

I'd like to print every line in my file that satisfies the following:

print line if column 3 or column 4 or column 5 is less than 10

Example

```
Emma   A  10  4  7
Sally  A  4   4  7
Jack   B  15  19 2
Jeff   C  15  20 25
Mary   A  15  20 25
Meg    C  2   7  9
```

Output

```
Emma   A  10  4  7
Sally  A  4   4  7
Jack   B  15  19 2 
Meg    C  2   7  9
```

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty simple with **`awk`**:

```
awk '$3<10 || $4<10 || $5<10' file
```

The output:

```
Emma A 10 4 7
Sally A 4 4 7
Jack B 15 19 2
Meg C 2 7 9
```